# Testing IO.Stream interaction

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing, dependency-injection, io

I have a method in my business logic layer that accepts a stream, which in the GUI comes from a user uploading a file, and I am interested in which is an appropriate way to test that the method appropriately uses this stream to make decisions.

```
public Sub Initialize(ByVal uploadStream As Stream)
    ''// Logic using uploadStream
End Sub
```

For testing purposes I wish to DI a mocked stream into this method, but I find a stiffling lack of abstraction whenever working with streams.

Intuition tells me that a need to create a Stream wrapper which would allow me to DI an interface of the wrapper to test interaction of my logic with the stream wapper.

What's the best way to proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want a way to pass in a "fake" upload, you could construct a [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) in your test harness and pass that in.

Answer (score 1):

I too tend to use a MemoryStream.  For some tests you might want to overload the Read method to return less than the requested number of bytes.  (I think a MemoryStream will always return the requested number of bytes, unless it'a reached the end of the stream, but a network stream can return less bytes than requested even before the end of the stream.)